# Migrate Current React JS Project to Run in Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, react, react-webpart

Our team has created a React SPA that is js based as opposed to ts. From what I've seen, creating and utilizing a webpart requires typescript. This project is fairly large so I guess I'm just wondering what our best option would be to get this SPA into Sharepoint. Is converting the project to typescript the best option? Are there other options to deploy a SPA into Sharepoint without creating a webpart?

The other thing with this is we would like to have a test site where this runs on its own, outside of Sharepoint. Would we essentially need 2 different code bases to do that?

Comment: Is it SharePoint Online? Or on-prem?

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov online

Comment: In order to answer your second question about separate code bases we need to know more about your code. Does your SPA call some APIs? How does it authenticate with these APIs? Does your SPA have a back-end? What is this back-end, etc. You minght need to create a separate question so that we can answer it fully.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three ways to create SPA in SharePoint Online:

1. Provider hosted app (Useful if you have server-side logic)
2. SPA SPFX webpart (Not a very good option as of August 2019), but will iprove later on
3. Custom SPA solution using HTML + CSS + JavaScript

Let's talk about Approach #3:

### **Custom SPA solution using HTML + CSS + JavaScript**

**Steps**

- Create an HTML page. Call it `SPA.HTML`. Add some Hello world HTML to the page.
- Rename the page to have .ASPX extension. Example: `SPA.ASPX`
- Upload your `SPA.ASPX` to `/SiteAssets/` library in SharePoint
- Navigate to your page `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/siteAssets/spa.aspx`
- You will see that your custom page takes up the entire screen and effectively, it's the real SPA.
- Done.

Your `SPA.ASPX` page will need some CSS and JavaScript files. Go ahead and upload them to the same `/SiteAssets/` library

**Things to consider**

- With this approach you are free to choose any freamework you want. React, Angular, Vue. Whether to choose TypeScript or not - your choice.
- This has nothing to do with SPFx. SharePoint will just act as a web server for hosting and serving your custom HTML files.
- make sure your main HTML file has .aspx extension instead of HTML
- It does not really matter where you upload your files. For example, you can use `/_catalogs/masterpage/` folder.

**Sample SPA project**

You can check out a sample SPA project. It used AngularJS, with zero typescript: https://github.com/Zerg00s/customSPA.

Just clone it and run `DEPLOY_ARTIFACTS.bat` to deploy it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Denis. The code does have a backend REST API that it calls for data. Initial authentication into the SPA is done with Azure AD and the react-aad-msal plugin, although I was thinking this may have been able to be replaced with the user context from SPFX. If we went with the solution you described above I'm assuming that would not be possible, and the user would have to reauthenticate, correct? What is the provider hosted app you mentioned?

Comment: [Provider hosted app](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-started-creating-provider-hosted-sharepoint-add-ins) is basically an external website that can be hosted, for example, in IIS. This site is surfaced in SharePoint via an iFrame. In your case it might be a good choice because you can reuse almost all of your code.